# Is it possible to use xsetroot and dwm to set the top and bottom bars at different time intervals?

Tags: x-server, dwm

I'm using dwm with the [dualstatus](http://dwm.suckless.org/patches/dualstatus) patch. This adds a status bar on the bottom of the screen, in addition to the standard bar at the top. The text in each bar is set in ~/.xinitrc (for example) like this:

```
xsetroot -name “top text;bottom text”
```

Is there a way in bash to set the top text and bottom text at different intervals? For example, I have a script `topbar` that displays system information, e.g. output from the uptime command, and a script `bottombar` that displays information like weather, battery state, etc.

The goal is to have the top bar update every second, while the bottom bar only updates every minute because its information comes from more expensive processes (e.g. querying my music player, checking the battery state, etc.) Right now my ~/.xinitrc looks like this:

```
while true; do
    bottomdisp=$(bottombar)
    for s in {1..60}
    do
        xsetroot -name "$(topbar);$bottomdisp";
    sleep 1;
    done
done &

xbindkeys
( ( sleep 5 && /usr/bin/xscreensaver -no-splash -display :0.0 ) & )

exec rundwm
```

This updates every second, though. Is there a simpler way to do this? The ideas I could think of were

1. Maybe a way to tell xsetroot to preserve whatever's in the bottom bar? As a last resort, I may tweak some of the code in the `dualstatus` patch to allow it to preserve the current state of the top/bottom bars if something like `xsetroot -name ';bottom text'` is passed, but that's not ideal because my C is rusty and I still use the above command to clear the bars at times.
2. Use a cronjob to update a cache of the text in the bottom bar, and run that once a minute. Even though the top/bottom bars would display every second, only the top bar would actually *change* every second.

Any other methods for this? Is there a simple(r) way to do this in bash that I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest having bash keep track of your previous bottom string and only update it once a minute (when seconds of the current time modulo 60 is equal to 0 in this code).

```bsh
while true; do 
    (( 10#$(date +%s) % 60 )) || bottomdisp=$(date)
    xsetroot -name "$(topbar);$bottomdisp";
    sleep 1;
done  &
```

This syntax makes it easy to modify the frequency of the secondary (or have  multiple) intervals, e.g. just change 60 to 15 for updates 4 times a minute.